# Regular expression which does not match a string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to find a regular expression which does not match the below string:

```
xxx_yyyyyy_zzz_aaaaa
xxx_yyyyyy_zzz_aaaaa_cat
xxx_yyyyyy_zzz_aaaaa_uom
```

My regular expression should get me only `xxx_yyyyyy_zzz_aaaaa` and not the ones which contain `_cat` and/or `_uom`. Basically I am trying to filter out rows with `_cat` and `_uom` from my rows using regex.

Comment: You need [`line anchors`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), i.e. `^xxx_yyyyyy_zzz_aaaaa$`

Comment: It could be anything xxx_yyyyyy_zzz_aaaaa is just a sample. it could also have yy_ff_ss_kk with yy_ff_ss_kk_cat and yy_ff_ss_kk_uom. I need to get only the yy_ff_ss_kk

Comment: `[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+){3}`

Comment: Okay should the string like this `xyz_catcome` match ?

Comment: No. Only xyz_cat can match. but xyz_cat can match. Basically anything with _cat or _uom at the end should be filtered out by the regex

Comment: [`^(?!.*_(cat|uom)$).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/DVVqCd/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?:[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)(?<!_cat|_uom)\b`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7aB2UJ/2)

Comment: Hi Matt. The regex should filter out any row with the values _cat and _uom at the end. It doesnt matter how many string groups are present in the front.

Comment: @vigneshasokan, I've updated the answer based on the new requirement

Comment: It is removing everything

Comment: what do you mean by "everything"?

Comment: It removed all 3 combinations instead of removing just the ones with _cat and _uom

Comment: see the Demo link in the answer, it only matches the ones without _cat or _uom at the end.